# CodeIgniter mod_rewrite with apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting mod_rewrite to work with CodeIgniter. I'm running apache 2.4.

My web root is /Users/Jason/Development/www

This is the code I currently have in my .htaccess file located in the same directory as my main index.php file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myapp/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting a 404 page saying the requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Check webserver logfiles

Comment: Is your app located in `www/myapp`?

Comment: Is apache mod_rewrite module enabeld ?

Comment: Check AllowOverride on Apache configure. This allows htaccess to run.

To test if htaccess works properly, type something wrong in it (Ex: abcdef at the beginning of htaccess). If you got an 500 error, htaccess is working, if error is still 404, I am sure you should find AllowOverride to enable it for your DocumentRoot.

Comment: Mike, yes, it is located there.

Comment: Than, I set AllowOverride All for my DocumentRoot and now im getting a 500 error but my .htaccess hasn't changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

 # exclude any paths that are not codeigniter-app related
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-info
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/docs

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]    
 </IfModule>    

# the following is for rewritting under FastCGI
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Base on sigmoid https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/2013/08/12/apache-tip-rewriting-urls-with-apache-2-4-php-fpm-mod_fastcgi_handler-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I needed.

Comment: Been battling with enabling HTTP/2 (and thus fastcgi etc) in a server with CI apps. I'm using PHP 7.3 but this seems to run fine. Thanks.